# Requirement failed in LogisticRegressionModel.predict

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want test my model (SparkMLlib) in JavaApplication

```
 LogisticRegressionModel sameModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc,"/home/storm/Desktotp/LogisticRegressionModel");
        Vector meu = Vectors.dense(1.0, 26.0, 0.4872, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.4925, 0.6182, 0.2762, 0.5468, 0.12, 9.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.12, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.4507, 0.0, 132.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 141.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0);
        Double prediction = sameModel.predict(meu);
```

When run, i have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.predictPoint(LogisticRegression.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearModel.predict(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:84)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the only requirement checked in `predictPoint` is an input vector size it most likely doesn't match a shape of the data used to train model.

An easy way to check if this is the case is to check `model.numFeatures` and compare it with a `size` of the input vector.